# Hierarchy of applying multiple DataTemplates to a single DataType

Tags: wpf

I've seen some allusions to this question around SO, but I haven't found a specific answer yet.

Say I have models, ObjectA and ObjectB, that inherit from BaseObject and have corresponding ViewModels, ObjectAViewModel and ObjectBViewModel.  Each is the DataType of a DataTemplate that is stored in a ResourceDictionary that represents how they are typically displayed in a View.

However, in certain circumstances, based on the View's design, I want to use a different DataTemplate for ObjectA that is stored in another ResourceDictionary, but still use the same DataTemplate for ObjectB.  Is this is situation where the order of the resource dictionaries matters?

I am in the process of refactoring an old project into WPF, and I am about a day or two away from structuring this part of the program.  So, I'll come up with an answer on my own in a couple days, but in case someone catches this sooner, I figured I wasn't the only one wondering about this.  What follows is the structure I have in my head for how this could work.

```
class BaseObject { }

class ObjectA : BaseObject { }
class ObjectB : BaseObject { }

class BaseObjectCollection : ICollection<BaseObject> { ObjectA; ObjectB; }

class ObjectAViewModel { }
class ObjectBViewModel { }

<!-- Main Resources File -->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ObjectAViewModel}" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ObjectBViewModel}" />
</ResourceDictionary>

<!-- Displays ObjectA, ObjectB using above Main Resource File DataTemplates -->
<Window x:Name="ViewA">
    <Window.Resources>
        <...code for grabbing Main Resources File... />
    </Window.Resources>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="_baseObjectCollection" />
</Window>

<!-- Second Resource File -->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ObjectAViewModel}" />
</ResourceDictionary>

<!-- What happens here? -->
<Window x:Name="ViewB">
    <Window.Resources>
        <...code for grabbing Main Resource File... />
        <...code for grabbing Second Resource File... />
    </Window.Resources>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="_baseObjectCollection" />
</Window>
```

Yes, I could use x:Key's and a TemplateSelector, but I would prefer to use the automatic selection process.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: It would be great if you could clarify your question a little bit. It is not clear what you're trying to achieve here, and what is your current result and how does it differ from the expected result.

Comment: I am working in this direction, but I am currently reworking how the models are structured and won't get to this for a while.  Basically, in the example, I am trying to have two DataTemplates apply to the same ViewModel with the later one overriding the previous one.  (Say, one has a Label, TextBlock and Button for display only, and the other has a Label, ComboBox and Button for editing purposes.)  If I employ this kind of strategy, will I get the expected result?  (@HighCore, the last time you answered a question of mine, you told me to delete everything, so I'm trying to avoid that. lol)